# Play video in service class

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer

I have an android application that plays videos in Mediaplayer. I am playing multiple videos through this media player class.

Now i would like to achieve playing media player through service class and i referred [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices).

I have many videos in my activity and here i would like to achieve playing videos at the background when user is in some other activity and when needs by calling the particular service where the video is running that video needs to play in foreground. I would like to achieve this using service class.

Can anyone help me in achieve this . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The document is clear but it doesn't provides a complete example and there are quite some tutorials created by the community.

This one
 https://github.com/vytiaganets/android-mp3-player
maybe the simplest, it is quite straight. It skips how to pass item playing to the service. Basically, you may add the url or path and pausing position in the intent to start the service, and do let the mplayer resume when it starts.

Comment: thanks for ur ans... can we add surface view in service class to play the videos? as videos can be played in surface view

Comment: Why do you want to do that? As it is playing in background, user cannot see it at all.

Comment: hope my question is not clear. I would like to play videos in service class at background when the user is in some other task and when they need by calling that particular service class that video needs to come in foreground. Is my question clear now?

Comment: Firstly, you should pause the player when user is answering a phone call, Activity lifecycle callbacks are good enough for this case. For other case, you may stop the service when your main activity get focus again.

Comment: can we create a surfaceview in service class and for this any of the examples are there?

Comment: And yes, you may create a surface view and pass it to player in the service.

Comment: can u post me an example of this so that it will be more clear.

Comment: You may simply new SurfaceView and setDisplay with it, but I guess it will bring you more confusion. I suggest you to reconsider the purpose of running this service.